# Bootstrap v3.3.x back to 16 Columns?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I downloaded the latest release of Bootstrap v3.3.2 and I notice a difference between v3.2.x 
col-md-3 seem to be using 18.75%(3/16) instead of 25% (3/12)
So does this means that Bootstrap has gone back to 16 columns rather than using the 12?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not by default, no. Are you sure you did not customize it (http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) and changed `@grid-columns` to 16?

Comment: Thanks. Just realized that the bootstrap I got from my client is modified

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap includes a responsive, mobile first fluid grid system that appropriately scales up to 12 columns as the device or viewport size increases. It includes predefined classes for easy layout options, as well as powerful mixins for generating more semantic layouts.